# Why AM-GM method can't be used to calculate the minimum value of $3\sin^2x+27\csc^2x$?

Tags: trigonometry, maxima-minima, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> Find the minimum value of $3\sin^2x+27\csc^2x$.

Using derivative, we get the answer is $30$.

Using AM-GM inequality or completing the whole square, we get the minimum is $18$.

The answer is $30$.

Why can't we use the AM-GM method or completing the whole square method here?

Comment: Simply because the ranges of the trigonometric functions under consideration for the application of inequality between the means is $\neq \mathbb{R}$, but  finite segments $\subseteq R$ (which in fact intersect at $2$ points to be precise) which can be seen easily by considering the equality case.

Comment: The AM-GM only gives you a lower bound and not necessarily a minimum.

Comment: @AmartyaShekhar Are you saying the AM-GM method is applicable when the range is $R$? and not otherwise?

Comment: @AnuragA Do you mind giving an example where we get only the lower bound with AM-GM inequality and not the minimum? Thanks.

Comment: Kind of, but not exactly, but when the ranges of the functions under consideration are distinct  finite subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ then I think it better to avoid the use the inequalities of means. Like in this case the ranges intersect at exactly $2$ points, therefore the inequality doesn't work , as simple as that

Comment: @AmartyaShekhar Sorry, I am not understanding the importance of intersection of ranges here.

Comment: @aarbee AM-GM says $x^2+4 \geq 2\sqrt{4x^2}=4|x| \geq 0$. But the minimum value for $x^2+4$ is $4$ (which is attained at $x=0$). So AM-GM only gave a lower bound but not the minimum.

Comment: @aarbee Consider , understanding the cases of equality in cases of application of the inequality of means

Comment: @AnuragA that's wonderful, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AM-GM method tells you that the equality only holds if $a=b$, i.e., in your case
$$3\sin^2 x=27 \csc^2 x$$
But, this can never be true as thuis implies
$$\sin^4 x=9$$
but we have
$$-1\leq\sin x\leq1$$
Does that help?

Comment: @AmartyaShekhar Because I messed up while typing :)